# python: how can i make my function stop reading through a list once its done what i want

Tags: python, list, function

i need to be able to paste up 4 sheets on to a billboard background using data from a list, here is a small segment of that list:

```
data_sets = [
# These two initial data sets don't put any sheets on the billboard
# Data sets 0 - 1
['O'],
['X'],
# These data sets put Sheet A in all possible locations and orientations
# Data sets 2 - 9
['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upright']],
['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 2', 'Upright']],
['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 3', 'Upright']],
['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 4', 'Upright']],
['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upside down']],
['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 2', 'Upside down']],
['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 3', 'Upside down']],
['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 4', 'Upside down']]
]
```

i'm trying to get the turtle to draw my sheet but it once it draws it, it keeps on going through the whole list and drawing the outlines, i need it to stop going through the list once it performs sheet_a_upright(). The 'x' and 'o' don't mean anything at this point, take no notice of them. the same thing was happening to my goto_loc() function but i fixed it by putting data_sets as a parameter, when i do this for the sheet() function, it ends up not drawing anything at all.

```
#location function for data_sets
def goto_loc(data_sets):
    for location in data_sets:
        if len(location)>1 and 'Location 1' in location[1]:
            goto(-300, 0)
        elif len(location)>1 and 'Location 2' in location[1]:
            goto(-100, 0)
        elif len(location)>1 and 'Location 3' in location[1]:
            goto(100, 0)
        elif len(location)>1 and 'Location 4' in location[1]:
            goto(300, 0)

#function for which sheet should be drawn from data_sets
def sheet():
    for style in data_sets:
        if len(style)>1 and 'Sheet A' in style[1]:
            sheet_a_upright()
        elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet B' in style[1]:
            sheet_b_upright()
        elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet C' in style[1]:
            sheet_c_upright()
        elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet D' in style[1]:
            sheet_d_upright()

#define sheet outline and fill
def outline():
    penup()
    forward(100)
    pendown()
    fillcolor('green')
    begin_fill()
    left(90)
    fd(250)
    left(90)
    fd(200)
    left(90)
    fd(500)
    left(90)
    fd(200)
    left(90)
    fd(250)
    right(90)
    penup()
    end_fill()

#function for sheet A in upright position
def sheet_a_upright():
    #sheet outline and fill
    outline()

# Paste the sheets onto the billboard as per the provided data set
def paste_up(data_sets):
    for each in data_sets:
        goto_loc(data_sets)
        sheet()

paste_up(data_sets[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your `sheet` function `return True` if `sheet_a_upright()` is executed.

```
def sheet():
            for style in data_sets:
                if len(style)>1 and 'Sheet A' in style[1]:
                    sheet_a_upright()
                    return True
                elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet B' in style[1]:
                    sheet_b_upright()
                elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet C' in style[1]:
                    sheet_c_upright()
                elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet D' in style[1]:
                    sheet_d_upright()
```

Then, in your `paste_up` function, check to see if `sheet()` is true:

```
def paste_up(data_sets):
            for each in data_sets:
                goto_loc(data_sets)
                if sheet():
                    return
```